# Ping status max player count code?

Tags: php

I have no idea how to word the title in a short manner, but I am quite the newbie when it comes to PHP, so I'm wondering if anyone can help identify what I'm doing wrong.

What I'm trying to accomplish is for a Minecraft Server Network - To tell people what the total maximum number of players can be online is by pinging each server and, with the manually set maximum, print just the number of players (so that I can later implement it).

This is what I've been messing around with (Pardon me for my variables =D):

```
<?php
$timecraftip = '76.92.80.28';
$timecraftport = 25567;
$timecraftcheckSock = @fsockopen($timecraftip, $timecraftport, $empty, $empty, 1);
$infiniteempireip = '63.135.57.11';
$infiniteempireport = 25565;
$infiniteempirecheckSock = @fsockopen($infiniteempireip, $infiniteempireport, $empty, $empty, 1);
$extremegamingip = '192.95.32.36';
$extremegamingport = 25700;
$extremegamingcheckSock = @fsockopen($extremegamingip, $extremegamingport, $empty, $empty, 1);

if($timecraftcheckSock !== FALSE)
    {
    $timecraft = 1;
    }else{
    $timecraft = 0;
    }
if($infiniteempirecheckSock !== FALSE)
    {
    $infiniteempire = 1;
    }else{
    $infiniteempire = 0;
    }
if($extremegamingcheckSock !== FALSE)
    {
    $extremegaming = 1;
    }else{
    $timecraft = 0;
    }

if($timecraft = 1 && $infiniteempire = 1 && $extremegaming = 1)
    {
    echo '130';
    }
if($timecraft = 1 && $infiniteempire = 1 && $extremegaming = 0)
    {
    echo '70';
    }
if($timecraft = 1 && $infiniteempire = 0 && $extremegaming = 1)
    {
    echo '110';
    }
if($timecraft = 0 && $infiniteempire = 1 && $extremegaming = 1)
    {
    echo '80';
    }
if($timecraft = 1 && $infiniteempire = 0 && $extremegaming = 0)
    {
    echo '50';
    }
if($timecraft = 0 && $infiniteempire = 1 && $extremegaming = 0)
    {
    echo '20';
    }
if($timecraft = 0 && $infiniteempire = 0 && $extremegaming = 1)
    {
    echo '60';
    }
if($timecraft = 0 && $infiniteempire = 0 && $extremegaming = 0)
    {
    echo '0';
    }
?>
```

So far, it prints "130" regardless of the server status.

Any and all help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to organize your data. Think about the problem. Make your code make more sense.  We have three servers, each of which has an IP, a port, and a number of players that can play

```
<?php
  $servers = ['timecraft' => 
                        [ 'ip' => '76.92.80.28', 'port' => 25567, 'players' => 50], 
              'infiniteempire' => 
                        [ 'ip' => '63.135.57.11', 'port' => 25565, 'players'=>20],
              'extremegaming' => 
                        [ 'ip' => '192.95.32.36', 'port' => 25700, 'players'=>60]
             ];
```

Now, since all we apparently need to do is get the overall value of these servers, based on it's response to fsockopen, we can use the `array_reduce` function, which reduces an array to a single value:

```
  $players = array_reduce($servers, function($total, $server) {
               if (@fsockopen($server['ip'], $server['port'], '', '', 1) {
                   $total += $server['players'];
               }
               return $total;
           });
```

This iterates through each server, and passes the value into the function we provided, storing the result as it goes along in `$total`.  Whatever `array_reduce` returns, we save in `$players`.

Now, we just have to echo the result:

```
echo $players;
```

Comment: All I get from this is "syntax error, unexpected '[' in...on line 2". I did mess around with it a bit, but still no luck. I'm not sure how to fix this, I don't know how to write PHP, only how to somewhat read it. In case it has something to do with my PHP version, I've got 5.5.